# How to set 'numlock on' as default at login screen in Kubuntu 20.10?

Tags: numlock

This is my keyboard settings on Kubuntu 20.10:

[image]

As you can see, numlock is on when plasma starts up; but it is not working. How can I fix it?

Note: I didn't choose keyboard model; because I don't know it. The chosen model is the default one.

Waiting for your reply,
Thank you.

Comment: If `numlockx` is installed on your system you can add the command of `numlockx on` to your startup.

Comment: I installed numlockx. What's the next step? :)

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using Kubuntu, so I can't write a great answer for you.  However, look in the settings for the Plasma desktop and see if there is anything for Startup.  If it allows you to add a startup item, all you need is the command of `numlockx on` added as a startup command named whatever you want.

Comment: There are two options in autostart section: 1) Add Program 2) Add Script. If I choose "add program", "numlockx" is not in the list. So I created a .txt file named numlockx.txt with the code "numlockx on" inside it and added the file as a script. But it didn't work. So I created a .sh file named numlockx.sh with the same code. It didn't work either. I'm not sure how to implement that "numlockx on" code as a script file. I'm newbie at these things.

Comment: Either your script needs to be executable (chmod +x numlockx.sh) with a beginning shebang line `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh`.  Or, load it via a command of `sh /path/to/numlockx.sh`

Comment: I did it as you suggested. On login screen the numlock is off; but after I login the numlock starts working and it is on. Can we make it as it starts on login screen? I'm using numbers for login.

Comment: When you create a startup like that it should create a file in your `~/.config/autostart/` folder.  If you copy that file to the `/etc/xdg/autostart/` folder then it should startup before logging in.   You will have to copy with elevated permissions:  `sudo cp filename.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/`

Comment: Good morning Terrance. Ok, I have both tried Numlockx.sh.desktop and Numlockx.desktop as I wasn't sure if I had to change ".sh" file extension; but coping either file to `/etc/xdg/autostart` didn't work. Numlock still starts after login. Any suggestions? :/

Comment: That's all I got as I don't use Plasma / KDE / Kubuntu.  Sorry about that.  However, take a look at https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/autostart/index.html as it might have clues where to copy the startups to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cant believe I keep google for this each time I reinstall :)

Leaving here the command that I ran in case it might be useful for less experienced users. or for the future myself:

open your terminal and run this (quotes et all):

`echo "Numlock=on" | sudo tee -a "/etc/sddm.conf"`

Comment: Finally it works! Thank you very much. However, The main reason I opened the thread was to get past the password screen in no time. Currently numlock is on, but now every time I open Kubuntu I have to click on the password input box with the mouse. Is it possible to enter numbers directly without clicking the box with the mouse? In Windows I log in exactly as I described.

Comment: Are you by chance using ubuntu 23.04 too? Let me summarize what I have found:
---
- Trying to press the numbers on the keypad part of the keyboard doesnt write anything into the password box 
- Pressing any a-Z or standar numbers on the keyboard, writes on the password box. Once you do this, its now possible to write using the numeric keypad -You can use alt+numbers on the keypad, and it will also write on the password field by default. This workaround is only needed for the first number.

I think its related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sddm/+bug/2018203

Answer (score 0):

Create or edit file /etc/sddm.conf and write "Numlock=on" inside.

Comment: Hello there! Thank you for your reply. That question was very old, today I have Kubuntu 23.04 (lunar), l’ve tried w/o quotations; none of them works. Any ideas?

Comment: @Stockfish Hello! I spent about one hour to find the answer and only this help with my LTS Kubuntu 22.04. Apparently it is not working in 23.04. 
I think is may be different display manager. In my 22.04 kubuntu it is [SDDM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SDDM). You can try to dig in that way. May be config in diffrent place, may be 23.04 use another display manager.

Comment: When I run: "sudo cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager" the result is: "/usr/bin/sddm". So I'm still using sddm. Should I use quototaion marks or not in sddm.conf file?

Comment: @Stockfish no, you not need quotes. It must be: `Numlock=on`